# How to create different "pages" in XNA?

Tags: c#, .net, xna

(I think I heard this being called a "state-based" game, but I'm not sure...)

Basically what I want to do is have my start screen be one class, and then it passes on control (of the window/drawing/updating) to another class (ie the game class) and I can pass back control to the start screen class from the actual game class.

*I want to switch logic control without opening a new window, and closing the original, but just seamlessly transfering to another class.*

EDIT: I'm not looking for anyone to tell me exactly how to do this, just please nudge me in the right direction because I couldn't find it on Google...

Comment: Questions without code are not a good fit for SO

Comment: I don't know where to start though, I looked up "state based games XNA", "pages in XNA", "making start screens in XNA", etc. and I couldn't find anything useful. besides, there are tons of questions with no code

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13248561/is-it-possible-to-set-a-subject-to-the-mail-app-in-windows-8-metro-application for example

Comment: I think it's a fair question. It's about implementing a particular "pattern" in XNA - e.g. how *would* one attach a different C to the same V (or whatever terminology XNA calls for).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a sample for that: [XNA Game State Management sample](http://xbox.create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/game_state_management).